# Significant figures.

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology, decimal-expansion

Calculate how many gram of p-nitrophenol you require to prepare 250 mL of a 11 mM solution. (Answer to 3 significant figures)

I worked it out as $$250/1000 L * (11*10^{-3}\text{ M})$$ = $$2.75\times 10^{-3} \text{ moles} \times 139.11\text{ g/mol}$$ = $$0.3825525$$

is that 0.383 or 0.382 when approximated to 3 sig figs?

Comment: The correct approximation is $0.383$

Comment: can you explain why? I know that my teacher always mentioned that we should up approx. a 5.. but she didn't explain why

Comment: Here you can find some rules:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rounding_and_decimal_places

Answer (score 0):

Note that ["*Leading zeros are never significant*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Identifying_significant_figures).

When approximating/rounding-off to n significant figures, your n-th digit should be rounded-off. In this case, ***your answer would be 0.383.***

Please refer to the Wiki link above and [this site](http://www.usca.edu/chemistry/genchem/sigfig.htm) for explanations and examples on working with significant digits.